# Why do old questions without any apparent activity get marked as active?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, questions, recent-activity

Why is it that some old questions will show recent activity yet when looking at the question page, nothing indicates any change?

For example, [How to combine with openvpn, dynamic-ip?](https://superuser.com/questions/114211/how-to-combine-with-openvpn-dynamic-ip) has its last activity marked as today, but there are no new comments, edits or answers.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**Community**](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community) digs them up once in a while, it is a system process that brings two old, unanswered questions to the front page every hour.

Comment: @studiohack, thanks for the answer!

Comment: [citation-required] on "... **two** ..."

Comment: You can just eyeball the questions list to see two per hour kicked up again. Citation by observation. @sat

Comment: that's right @Sathya, @random is correct. I remember observing it, *and* reading about it somewhere, but I don't think I can find it again.

Comment: ok fair enough Studio & @random

Comment: What? Why, here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped/